# How to put parameterized sql query into variable and then execute in Python?

Tags: python, sql

I understand that the correct way to format a sql query in Python is like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", var1, var2, var3)
```

so that it prevents sql injection. My question is if there is a way to put the query in a variable and then execute it? I have tried the example below but receive an error. Is it possible to do this?

```
sql="INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", var1, var2, var3
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the call signature for cursor.execute:

```
Definition: cursor.execute(self, query, args=None)

    query -- string, query to execute on server
    args -- optional sequence or mapping, parameters to use with query.
```

So execute expects at most 3 arguments (args is optional).
If args is given, it is expected to be a sequence.
so

```
sql_and_params = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", var1, var2, var3
cursor.execute(*sql_and_params)
```

is not going to work, because

```
cursor.execute(*sql_and_params)
```

expands the tuple sql_and_params into 4 arguments (and again, execute only expects 3).

If you really must use

```
sql_and_params = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", var1, var2, var3
```

then you'll have to break it apart when feeding it to `cursor.execute`:

```
cursor.execute(sql_and_params[0],sql_and_params[1:])
```

But I think it feels much more pleasant to just use two variables:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
args= var1, var2, var3
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're pretty close.

```
sql_and_params = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", var1, var2, var3
cursor.execute(*sql_and_params)
```

The asterisk means that the variable isn't to be considered as one parameter but instead unpacked into many parameters.

Comment: why did you use `,` instead of `%`? For example to do this:

`sql_and_params = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (var1, var2, var3)`

Comment: @bzupnick using simple string formatting (the `%` operator), or substitution, would potentially allow SQL injection, not to mention failing to add quotation marks to the literals if needed.  Parameterized queries are highly superior to formatted/substituted queries.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Querying Microsoft SQL Server using pyodbc.

```
cusotmer_list = ['ABC', '123']

# parameterized query placeholders
placeholders = ",".join("?" * len(customer_list))

# query table
query = 
"""
SELECT
[ID],
[Customer]
FROM xyz.dbo.abc
WHERE [Customer] IN (%s)
""" % placeholders

# read query results in pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=cnxn, params=customer_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way for pass parameters to SQL query in Python is:

```
"INSERT INTO table VALUES (:1, :2, :3)  ", [val1, val2, val3]
```

or another example:

```
"UPDATE table T SET T.column2 = :1 where T.column1= :2 ", [val1,val2]
```