# Python Dynamic Parameterized Query

Tags: python, python-2.7, prepared-statement

I'm hoping to create a build a query dynamically that I can populate through paramerters. E.g. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, ...)
```

Then I want to populate it like shown in 
[How to put parameterized sql query into variable and then execute in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633332/how-to-put-parameterized-sql-query-into-variable-and-then-execute-in-python) :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
args= var1, var2, var3
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Building the query string above should be pretty easy, however I'm not sure how to build the list of args. Once I can do that, the rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my question was easier than I thought, it looks like arrays behave like lists in python. The following gave me what I needed:

```
results = []

results.append("a")
results.append("b")
results.append("c")
results.append("d")

print results
```

I can use the above to make my arg list.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use something like this to achieve what you describe:

```
>>> def prepquery(qrystr, args):
...   # Assumes Qry Str has a %s in it instead of column placeholders.
...   return qrystr % ', '.join('?' * len(args)) # ['%s'] * len(args), depending on DB.
...
>>>
>>> prepquery('Insert Into Table Values (%s)', range(5))
'Insert Into Table Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
```