# Faster way to do mysql query in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, performance

There are list1 and list2, each contains 1,104,824 values

table1 has 350,000,000 rows with 3 columns:  ID, name1, name2

and this is what I tried to do:

```
con = mdb.connect('localhost','user','password','db')
cur = con.cursor()
for i in range(1104824)
    sql ="select count(distinct(a.ID)) from (select name1 ,ID from table1 where name2 <> '"+str(list1[i])+"') as a where a.name1 = '"+str(list2[i])+"'"
    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

but it is very very slow. Is there any faster way to do this query?

Comment: post the table structure and what exactly you are trying to do. Surely there might be a way that does not involve 1.1 million queries?

Comment: If `ID` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, you can probably change `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)` to `COUNT(*)`.  If `name1,name2` is UNIQUE, you can probably get rid of `ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select count(distinct a.ID)
from (select name1, ID
      from table1
       where name2 <> '"+str(list1[i])+"'
      ) a
where a.name1 = '"+str(list2[i])+"'";
```

I would recommend writing this as:

```
select count(distinct ID)
from table1
where name2 <> '"+str(list1[i])+"' and
      name1 = '"+str(list2[i])+"'";
```

Then you can speed up the query with an index on `table1(name1, name2, id)` -- all three columns in that order.

Note:  I would write the sql as:

```
    sql = """
select count(distinct ID)
from table1
where name2 <> '{0}' and name1 = '{1}'
""".format(str(list1[i]), str(list2[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this would work as well with the appropriate indices:

```
select count(distinct id) 
from table1
where name2 <> 'Name1'
   and name1 = 'Name2'
```

Look into using parameterized queries though.  Your query is vulnerable to sql injection and would break for names with apostrophes for example... Lots of examples out there, here's a couple: [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633589/1073631