# python replace placeholder values in a string

Tags: python

I have below requirement in python,where I need to pass date and id at run time.

```
query_str="select * from test_table where data_date = '${data_date}' and id = ${id}"

Where data_date is string column and id is big int column.
```

If i'm passing data_date as 2015-01-01 and id as  1, it should replace the parameters as below.

```
Output : select * from test_table where data_date = '2015-01-01' and id = 1
```

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

What you are actually asking about is called [*query parameterization*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633332/how-to-put-parameterized-sql-query-into-variable-and-then-execute-in-python) and it has to be done right relying on what your database driver provides. This way you let your driver handle the proper escaping and python-to-database type conversions.

Depending on the driver, the placeholder style can differ, but `%s` is the most common:

```
query_str = """
    select * 
    from test_table 
    where data_date = %s and id = %s
"""
params = ('2015-01-01', 1)
cursor.execute(query_str, params)
```

where `cursor` is your database connection cursor instance.

Comment: This query parameterization is for pyspark SQL execution. I couldn't find any database driver for this purpose. That's the reason I'm looking for parameterization using python functions and execute the parameterized query.