# How can I delete a record using MySQL in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a database table called `Students` and I want to delete a record using SQL. Here is my code:

```
uid = int(input("Please enter students ID: "))
c.execute("DELETE FROM Students WHERE ID = (uid) ")
```

I want to input the `ID` variable (`uid`) into the `c.execute`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you are looking for: `c.execute("DELETE FROM Students WHERE ID = {} ".format(uid))`

Comment: @JustRufus Keep in mind that this example is exposed to SQL injection.

Comment: It is not, as it's int... you can't inject any code with int.

Answer (score 3):

You must not use string interpolation as recommended in the other answer; while in this specific case it might be OK, generally it is unsafe as it opens you up to SQL injection. Instead, use the support for parameters in the `execute` method:

```
uid = int(input("Please enter students ID: "))
c.execute("DELETE FROM Students WHERE ID = %s", (uid,))
```

Answer (score 1):

What Daniel Roseman said should be the correct answer.

You can insert the ID as a parameter for the .execute method. There is an answer about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633589/5559512)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the syntax is:

```
"some string: %s, some int: %i, some double: %d" % (string_var,int_var,double_var)
```

so:

```
uid = int(input("Please enter students ID: "))
c.execute("DELETE FROM Students WHERE ID = %i" % (uid))
```

Comment: This code is exposed to SQL injection. OP should use a parameterized query.

Comment: Not really... it is int... not vulnerable.

Comment: And tomorrow OP will try to use a string in the same fashion.

Comment: Maybe, but this code is fine. Giving `-1` because I don't agree with you? Oh ok.

Comment: But why recommend potentially unsafe code when there is a built-in way of making it safe?

Comment: Because the question in my opinion doesn't have anything to do with databases, but variable in variable. Of course it is not safe to use this with strings...

Comment: What? I can't understand how you can say that. This question is *entirely* about how to interpolate a variable into a database call. It is unquestionably *unsafe* to use string formatting to do that, which is why the database API provides a safe supported way to do it.

Comment: @FlashThunder Not because I don't agree with you, but because this answer recommends to use unsafe code. There's a big difference.